# Send an alert when user tabs into an iframe

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an alert box pop up when a user tabs into an iframe. I can't get the alert box to pop up.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which == "9") {
        let iframeSelector = document.querySelector("iframe")
        if (document.activeElement == iframeSelector) {
            alert("test");
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by adding a setTimeout of 0 around your if statement, like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which == "9") {
        let iframeSelector = document.querySelector("iframe")
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (document.activeElement == iframeSelector) {
                alert("test");
            }
        }, 0)
    }
})
```

I believe this happens because when the `keydown` event fires, the `activeElement` is still the previous focused thing. It seems like it should then work with `keyup` instead, but in my testing it doesn't.

So this solution seems a little hacky, but it did work in my testing.

Comment: Thanks Miles, this is really curious. In other words would you say the timeout here essentially removing the delay between the keypress and if condition?